# Route the traffic based on user token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, traefik, lambda-authorizer

I have an application where I want to route the traffic to different services based on user-token. That is if the user token is present in a database table then I want to route it to service V1 otherwise service V0. This is to migrate a customer from old system to new system. I want migrate few set of customers based on configuration. I think this can be using AWS gateway and lambda authorizer but I want to know if there are any better solutions. If solution is for traefik then it is most welcomed as I am using traefik currently.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a custom CloudFront distribution and swap the origin or path in lambda@edge. However abstracting away the API version kind of defeats the purpose of versioning in the first place.